# How to continue set text on edit text field?

Tags: android, android-edittext, settext

I have edit text field and set text to them, but when I set another text, past text is missing. How to continue entering text?

Comment: Please show your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
final String originalTextFromEditTextView = editTextView.getText().toString();
editTextView.setText(originalTextFromEditTextView + yourText);
```